# Administration threatening expulsion over absences in audited class

Tags: united-states

I just received an email from my school's administration (Pima medical if that means anything) that due to having an average of over 15% absence from class, I have to meet with someone from student services and administration where I may be expelled from the school.

For context, I'm retaking two of this semester's classes, and auditing a third as a reference before the end of program certification exam. The audited class is where most of the absences are, largely due to unexpected sickness or severely spraining my ankle. At the beginning of the semester, I was under the impression that the audited class would not be counted for grading or attendance, as that's how most other schools seem to handle it, but only recently realized that they don't see it that way.

I have the meeting with admin Monday after my classes, what would the best course of action be in the meeting, and is there anything I could/do beforehand or after for damage control and to make it go as smoothly as possible.

Comment: Go to the meeting, explain what happened. Try to get the lecturer from the class you audited to support you. I honestly don’t think there’s much you can do if you’re expelled, but I don’t think it’s the likely outcome. You’ll get a warning or something.

Comment: In addition to @Spark's advice, if you can get doctor's notes or records of medical treatment for your ankle and/or illnesses you should take that to the meeting.

Comment: Sometimes university student associations offer advocacy services, where a more experienced senior student may accompany you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll go in to the meeting and do my best to explain the situation. Unfortunately, the professor has already been very unsupportive, and I don't think I'll get any help there.